# Get DataGridView row at specified Y coordinate

Tags: .net, datagridview, location, vertical-scrolling

**The Problem**

I am attempting to link an external vertical scrollbar to a datagridview. I need an external scrollbar as I want it to be constantly visible whether there are an excess of rows or not. Sounded simple when I started but I am having trouble with resizing rows.

**The Attempts**

I have attempted to scroll per row (Scrollbar maximum being the row count, small change being 1, large change being the count of displayed rows). This did not work because of the ability to resize rows as this changes the amount of displayed rows which in turn sets the large change and therefore screws up the scroll bar.

I came to the conclusion that the best way was to scroll by pixel values. Default DGV behavior scrolls by row and not pixels so I need to convert a pixel value into a row index so I can set the FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex property. However, I am looking for a method to get the row at a specific point. I have tried HitTestInfo but this seems to only work for displayed rows and not rows that are out of view.

The best way I have found to do it so far is to Lambda loop through the rows and find which row falls within the Y coordinate.

```
    Dim Block As Integer = If(DGV.ColumnHeadersVisible, -DGV.ColumnHeadersHeight, 0)
    Dim ScrollToRow As DataGridViewRow = DGV.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).FirstOrDefault(Function(x)
                                                                                              Block += x.Height
                                                                                              Return Block >= VSB.Value
                                                                                          End Function)
    DGV.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = If(ScrollToRow IsNot Nothing, ScrollToRow.Index, 0)
```

**The Question**

Is there a method I am missing that can give me a row or its index by a Y coordinate? Obviously this should include rows that are not currently being displayed.

Alternatively, any other suggestions on how I can do this?

Comment: try datagridview.pointtoclient ..

Comment: That gives me a Point, I want the row index dependent on a Point

Answer (score 0):

Below static function was tested in VS-2019 WinForms with and without visible DataGridView headers. The pixel position (X,Y) must be relative to the client region of the control. The function will yield (cr, cc) for row and column at (X,Y)

- When pixel position (X,Y) is in a row header or column header of the grid, it will return TRUE (we are in the grid), and -1 for the corresponding row (cr) or column (cc) coordinate.
- When the pixel position (X,Y) is inside the data part of the grid, it  will also return TRUE and provide (cr, cc) starting at (0,0).
- This function will yield FALSE when the specified pixel is outside the grid region.

The language for the question is not tagged, so I provide my function in C# instead of Basic.

```
    private static bool FindPixelPositionInGrid(DataGridView dg, int X, int Y, out int cr, out int cc)
    {
        int rblck = dg.ColumnHeadersVisible ? dg.ColumnHeadersHeight : 0;
        bool foundcr = false;
        cc = cr = -1;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dg.Rows)
        {
            if (rblck > Y) break;
            rblck += r.Height; cr++;
        }
        if (rblck > Y)
        {
            cc = -1;
            var cblck = dg.RowHeadersVisible ? dg.RowHeadersWidth : 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dg.Columns)
            {
                if (cblck > X)
                {
                    foundcr = true;
                    break;
                }
                cblck += c.Width; cc++;
            }
            if (cblck > X) foundcr = true;
        }
        return foundcr;
    }
```